# Objective-C format date and string

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsdate

guys

I have two question to ask, they're easy, but bothering me for a while.

I access my .NET test WebService, and it return two parameters to me.

One is a date data just like "/Date(1332399761677+0800)/", and I dont know

how to format it to the normal date format.

Two is a NSString data looks like "12000.00000",and I want to change it to

the format like this:"12000.00".

So,please help me with this two problems. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`1332399761677` looks like a Unix date, so if you grab that part of the string, use `NSString doubleValue` to turn it into a double, then use `NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:`, you should be able to get a date. `+0800` looks like a timezone, but you wouldn't need the timezone to get the date given a Unix date: `1332399761677` would specify a specific point in time, irrespective of timezones.

As for "12000.00000", you would use `doubleValue` to make it into a double, make an `NSNumberFormatter` with its `maximumFractionDigits` and `minimumFractionDigits` set to 2, then use `stringFromNumber:`.

Comment: Thank you, let me have a try.